# Sequelize cannot use build

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js

This is my model class. It is located in a file called user.js:

```
const { Sequelize, Model, DataTypes} = require('sequelize');


class User extends Model{
    

    static Init(sequelize){
        var model = sequelize.define('user',{
            id: {type:Sequelize.UUID, defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4, primaryKey:true},
            username: {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false},
            password: {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false},
            name: {type:DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false},
        });
        return model;
    }

    GetName(){
        return this.name;
    }

};

module.exports = { User };
```

When I try to call the Sequelize build function from my app.js, I get this error:

> C:\Users\testenv\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:130
> if (this.constructor.primaryKeyAttributes.length) {
> ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
> at User._initValues (C:\Users\testenv\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:130:49)
> at new Model (C:\Users\testenv\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:116:10)
> at new User (C:\Users\testenv\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\modals\user.js:4:1)
> at Function.build (C:\Users\testenv\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1311:12)
> at initialize (C:\Users\testenv\Documents\Development\NodeJS\simple-express-project\app.js:26:19)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

I have traced it to the app.js line 26 which is:

```
var nu = User.build({
        username: "test"
})
```

I can't seem to access the properties of User in the build as well.

Comment: If you extending Model class then use `User.init` instead of calling `define`, see https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html#extending--a-href-----class-src-model-js-model-html--model--a-

Comment: Hi @Anatoly, but if I use User.init, how do I reference it outside the class?

Comment: Referenece what exactly?

Comment: Sorry I was trying to get help for another question of mine here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71263538/express-js-how-to-reference-a-sequelize-class